# How does Timed Publishing work for new versions (updates) in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application

I know that Time Publishing works for store listings such as description and screenshots. But I am not sure how it works for releasing a new version. I want to upload apk, create a release and add the new description and screenshots and keep everything ready for production and go live in a launching event.

But my question is there is only one button "Start rollout to Production" in release. If I click it, will it be submitted for production right away? How do I control exact time to go live?
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out myself. New apk will not go to Play Store until I hit "Go Live" button.

Comment: Even Play Store notifies you that: "You just updated this application. It can take several hours until the changes are visible in Google Play." it's a lie. If timed pusblishing is enabled, build will be released publicly aonly after you press "Go live" button.  Moreover such update of binaries isn't visible in "Timed publishing change log".

Comment: @Alex_297 thanks for the life-saving comment. I almost died from worry that I had just rolled out an update to production when my change log was empty

Comment: to confirm, if I press "start rollout"  it won't release until I press "Go live" after, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same behavior, except when I click "Start rollout to Production", I see a warning message saying, "Your app will now become available to all users of the Play Store. Do you want to continue?".....  Nooo, we want to use Timed Publishing!  :-)  So, I think Timed Publishing doesn't pertain to the first time you publish -- only to app **updates**.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Timed Publishing works only for updates.